# How do i tell a form not to be close if a backgroundworker is busy?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void ScanClouds_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
    }
    Terminate();
}
```

Beside calling the CancelAsync i also want to tell the form to not be close.
And then in the completed event i'm closing the form:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

The question is when i click to close the form how do i tell him not to be close and to close it in the completed event ?

Comment: I did added now the e.Cancel = true; and only when added this line when closing the form it went into the backgroundworker do work event if (bgw.CancellationPending == true) and inside did: break; and this is what i wanted to cancel the backgroundworker operation in the middle when closing the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (bgWorker.IsBusy)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can override the [`OnFormClosing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, to prevent the form from closing. Set [`e.Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

You could show a message box inside or do anything else to inform the user why you cancelled the closing.

Comment: *Refusing* to close a form is  a very bad user experience.

Comment: I didn't argue that. You could of course give the user the option. "Are you really really really sure?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void ScanClouds_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
e.Cancel = true;
    }
    Terminate();
}
```

you could also write `e.Cancel=true` in MyForm_FormClosing like above because it also internally calls OnFormClosing method of form.

Answer (score 0):

Is a bad form to *refuse* to do the user action. Instead you should indicate, with visual feed-back and clues, that the form is not Close-able. For instance, set [`ControlBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox(v=vs.110).aspx) to `False` while the background job is running.

You can also leave the form closeable, and *abort* the background task when the form is closed. Which, of course, require cooperation from the task (not all tasks are abortable).